# Laptop battery swollen--how to proceed?

Tags: laptop, battery

Over the course of weeks, the batteries in my laptop have swollen gradually, forcing open the casing. Only recently was I informed that this can be dangerous, leading the batteries to explode. I'm in contact with the manufacturer now, but communicating with them takes time (the warranty is expired) and I sort of feel like there's a ticking time bomb in my room now after seeing some videos of laptop batteries exploding.

So should I try to remove the batteries myself and dispose of them, or is physical manipulation unsafe and I should wait for a professional to pick it up? I even phoned a computer store, but they didn't want anything to do with it. It's a Gigabyte P34 type laptop.

Comment: Google a manual for that model and see what it takes to remove and/or replace it yourself. If there is significant damage to the rest of the machine, however, you may need to replace more than just a the battery.

Comment: [Related](https://superuser.com/questions/1104271/how-to-safely-store-a-defective-bulging-lithium-ion-battery), but not quite a duplicate (this is about physical manipulation and removal while the linked question is about *storing* a battery already removed).

Comment: Thanks, according to some manuals I found, my battery might or might not be glued to the casing. I'll try to open the laptop and see if I can remove it easily. Anecdotal advice from here and in the other thread suggests that it's not highly likely to blow up into my face...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty common failure mode for lithium polymer batteries (though this sometimes happens with prismatic Li-ion cells as well). RC hobbyists encounter this sort of failure pretty often, and I've dealt with this failure mode myself. Even though the battery has failed, it shouldn't ignite or explode if you don't physically abuse the battery or tamper with it.

If you can disconnect the battery from the laptop without damaging the rest of the system, you should do so. The battery is wired to the motherboard but should not be too difficult to remove if you're comfortable working with electronics. Handle the battery carefully and store it in a fireproof container if possible; otherwise, isolate the battery to limit property damage should it catch fire. Contact the local fire department, waste disposal agency, or other government service for safe disposal.

This is a failed battery from an old Android tablet:

[image: Swollen LiPo battery from tablet]

Comment: Where you say "safe removal" shouldn't it be "safe disposal"?

Comment: I did it. The battery was glued to the casing so I had to yank it quite a bit, what a thrill. Laptop still works so all ended well!