# Why does the Lithium-Ion computer batteries make horrible smells after being stabbed ( and got in tact with Oxygen)?

Tags: laptop, battery

Recently my laptops just died.

So I decided to get my hands dirty and open up the motherboard.

- Open up everything in order to gain some valuable knowledge.

Long story short, I found some interest in the existence of the battery, so I opened it up, not just out of the board, I stabbed it and took off the main cover, and the battery started to make a bothering smell out of itself.

I thought it's because of the cover glue, but after some investigation I found that it's not.

I would be glad if a professional hardware engineer points me in the right direction about why the battery smell like this.

Comment: I stabbed [the battery]and took off the main cover, and the battery started to make a bothering smell out of itself.   .....   And you expected different ????

Comment: “Odor: If you notice a strong or unusual odor coming from the battery, this is also a bad sign. Li-ion batteries emit toxic fumes when they fail.”Found [here](https://www.albany.edu/facilities/plant/pdf/Lithium_Ion_Safety_Bulletin.pdf). More discussion can be [found here](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/562648/). Why should it not have a smell?

Comment: the valuable knowledge is `do not destroy everything`

Comment: Close voters. I think this one should stay open as a valuable lesson in "what not to do".

Comment: The valuable knowledge is that lithium chemistry is not something you want to be breathing in and puncturing batteries is a good way to create fires and fumes that are hazardous to your health. Chemistry is not a problem with computer hardware or software. The [chemicals involved are generally not pleasant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_hexafluorophosphate) and one of the gases may well be a highly toxic hydrogen fluoride gas.

Comment: @Tetsujin It is not on topic here in my opinion, even as a "what not to do" so being closed is appropriate but with an upvoted answer it will still exist and not be deleted. It can stay as it is currently as it will continue to be available but being closed should mean it does not encourage questions along the lines of "I poured concentrated sulphuric acid on my motherboard and it melted, what gives?"

Comment: @Khode you are driving your question further off-topic. Chemistry questions are off topic here.

Comment: Unless you are using some no-name stuff, it says it right on the cover of the battery: `DON'T OPEN OR EXPOSE TO HEAT`, I would suggest you read the manual before you do something else you might regret!

Answer (score 3):

Think yourself lucky you didn't just die in a fire.
You need to find a bucket of sand to put that in, or leave it in the middle of the garden, away from anything inflammable, until it can be disposed of safely. Don't throw it in the bin for the city refuse to collect. Take it, in the bucket, to a safe disposal facility.

Here's just a random selection of images found by searching "li ion fire" [lithium-ion, which is what computer batteries are made from].

[image]

See also - [How to safely store a defective (bulging) lithium-ion battery](https://superuser.com/questions/1104271/how-to-safely-store-a-defective-bulging-lithium-ion-battery?rq=1)

TL:DR: Treat computer batteries with the same respect you would dynamite or nitro-glycerine. They will kill if treated improperly.

Comment: You have saved my life, thank you.

Comment: Welcome. You have now gained some valuable knowledge - do your research **before** embarking on any new venture or experiment.